# How to add <div title="test"></div> like property for jquery-ui dialog buttons

Tags: css, jquery-ui, html, jquery-ui-dialog

Is there any attribute in dialog of jquery-ui which can provide behavior  like title property of div.(Showing title name on hover)?

Below is  generated html of **OK** button of confirm dialog box.I want 'title' like property of div to be applied for 'OK' and 'Cancel' button

```
<button type="button" class="ui-button 
        ui-widget 
        ui-state-default 
        ui-corner-all 
        ui-button-text-only"   role="button" aria-disabled="false">
     <span class="ui-button-text">Ok</span> </button>
```

***EDIT:***
Here are some property whihc I used for dialog

```
 dialog({

        height:110,
        widht:460,
        title:"This is dialog Title",
        modal: true,

        buttons: {
        "Ok": function() {  
        $( this ).dialog( 'destroy');
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( 'destroy');
        }
        },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any option to apply title attribute for buttons of jquery dialog.Here is the solution I am using as of now.

```
open: function(event, ui) {
      //  In dialog open
        $('.ui-dialog-buttonset button:first').attr('title','Ok');
        $('.ui-dialog-buttonset button:last').attr('title','Cancel');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the attribute **title** is what you are looking for.
http://www.quackit.com/html/tags/html_button_tag.cfm

Comment: Indeed,but not 'dialogTitle'.Title for 'OK' and 'Cancel' button

Comment: @sandy Add the attribute to the button? It can be added to any element basically.

Comment: sorry, do not understand: **title** does not work for the dialog?

Comment: Edited question,hope its understandable now.

Answer (score 1):

Put the title attribute in your HTML markup that you're applying the dialog to.

```
<div title="I show on hover!">...</div>
...
$('div').dialog(...);
```